# How to see entire website in mobile device? Not responsive website

Tags: css

I have this [site](http://www.canalonesbastimar.com) and [this](http://www.ovra.es).

I didn't add yet to them media queries (maybe in some weeks..) , but if you load the first one on a mobile phone, you will see the entire site, but if you load the second one, you will see just a part..in this latter case, how can I do to see the entire site in a mobile phone as he fist one site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [viewport meta tag](http://www.paulund.co.uk/understanding-the-viewport-meta-tag) there:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

While it's good for responsive websites, right now you might be better off without it.

Comment: thanks but it didn't work.. so I removed the line, to keep the document as before.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: that line *exists* on www.ovra.es and needs to be removed so the full page would show without having to zoom out / pan around it.